# Show UIWebView inside UINavigationController on a Modal view without NIB

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview, uinavigationcontroller, orientation

I have a requirement to load a UIWebView wrapped inside a UINavigationController, and show it on a modal view. UINavigationController should show the navigation bar at the top with a 'back' (I did not find back button, so I used 'done' button). I am not supposed to use a nib, so I have to do it programmatically only. The code has to basically serve as a library which can be integrated with any application. It has to work for IPhone and IPad, both.

This is what I have done so far:

I created a WebViewController class -

```
@interface WebViewController : UIViewController
{
    UIWebView *m_cWebView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *m_cWebView;

@end

- (void)loadView
{
    CGRect webFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    webFrame.size.height -= self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
    UIWebView *pWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame];
    pWebView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    pWebView.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);
    self.view = pWebView;
    pWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    self.m_cWebView = pWebView;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(back:)];  
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if( m_cWebView != nil )
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.co.in"];
        NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [m_cWebView loadRequest:request];
    }
}


- (IBAction)back:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    return nil;
}

- (id)init
{
    return self;
}
```

In the main view controller

```
@property (retain, atomic) UINavigationController *navCon;

-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    if( navCon == nil )
    {
        WebViewController* webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] init];
        navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:webViewController];

    }

    [self presentModalViewController:navCon animated:YES];

}
```

So far, it is working fine. Now my issues:

1. I am totally new to iOS world. Is the above code correct or are there issues?
2. Code is supposed to be compiled with Xcode 4.2 with ARC, so I presume that I don't need to worry about memory.
3. Is the logic to calculate the initial size of WebView correct (I am taking the size of main screen and deducting the height of navigation bar)?
4. How do I handle orientation change such that on changing the orientation, my Navigation View and WebView both adjust to the new orientation?

Thanks

Edit:

I tried implementing with the rotation, but I have not been able to get it to work. willRotateToInterfaceOrientation is not getting called on my WebViewController, even though I am returning YES from shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation ( and this method is getting called ). When I tried working with an empty nib ( loading WebViewController with this empty nib ), then it works fine.

Adding the 5th requirement:

1. One more additional requirement is that when this modal dialog dismisses, the view which presented this, should be in correct orientation (i.e. while the modal dialog is up, the orientation events are also passed on to the view which presented this modal view).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the fix to the rotation problem.
Replace

```
- (id)init
{
    return self;
}
```

with

```
- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
        return self;
    return nil;
}
```

and completely remove the following method:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    return nil;
}
```

Silly mistakes :)
Now it is rotating fine.

Can someone still comments on the original requirements?

Answer (score 1):

Some points from my side.

1. Regarding back button, in place of done:

   self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil] autorelease];
2. Height of navigation bar is always 44.0f
3. You can handle orientation change with these methods:

   - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

   return YES;
   }

   - (void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
     [self adjustViewsForOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation]; // adjust your view frames here
     }

I am not sure about your code and memory issues in that - so i could not comment over those.

Hope this information would be helpful to you.

Comment: Hi mrunal, thanks for the tip:
The back button worked with some tweak.
I am returning YES from shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation but willRotateToInterfaceOrientation is not getting called.

I would like to emphasize that WebViewController view is UIWebView itself.

One more additional requirement is that when this modal dialog dismisses, the view which presented this, should be in correct orientation (i.e. while the modal dialog is up, it also pass on the orientation change events to the view which presented this modal view).